# Where is Treasure Map part 7?

Tags: balrum

In the first chapter of Balrum you can collect an 8-part treasure map.
I think I have explored everything in the Darkwood, but I'm missing Treasure map part 7.

Where ist it?

Answer (score -1):

Just north of Fox's house. You get the quest after you find the locked door.

Comment: I checked the location you described. The triangle door northeast of Fox's house, yes? I found a document for Neil in there, but no treasure map.

Answer (score -1):

It's in the cave with many levers, in the NE quadrant.